# how object.constructor() works?

Tags: javascript

Recently I have attended one interview, Interviewer asked one interesting question have a look

```js
 function MyClass(){
        this.a = 10;
        return 20; // Interesting part
    }
    
    var obj1 = new MyClass();
    console.log(obj1.a); //  10 works as expected.
    console.log(obj1.constructor()); // 20 later I found this
```

> **how will you access return value(20) from obj1?**

I found the answer after looking proto of the obj1.
**obj1.constructor()** Works as expected

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 4):

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new):

> The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of the whole new expression. **If the constructor function doesn't explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used instead.** (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation process.)

The `20` goes nowhere and cannot be accessed. It isn't an object, so the instance of MyCass is returned instead.

Comment: It goes nowhere when you call `MyClass` with a  `new`. But if you call `MyClass` like any other function you get `20`.

Comment: I know but his question was how you will access from the object.

Comment: @RahulSharma — I said **it cannot be accessed**

Comment: @Quentin we can access that. I have updated question have a look. sorry i missed before

Comment: @RahulSharma — No. That requires running the constructor function again. The `20` being accessed is a **different** `20`